# Div is not aligned properly when animation is running

Tags: css, css-animations

[image]I'm trying to achieve an bell ringing animation. I have completely made a bell alike sample using pure css. When i set animation-delay property to .bell class my inner div seems to be hidden or misplaced. It's visible only after the animation is over. More better understanding i have attached the code below please refer.

```css
.bell{
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  width: 18px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
  background: #6d6d6d;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  animation: swinging .3s linear alternate;
  animation-delay:2s
}
.bell div{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 120%;
  background: #6d6d6d;
  left: -2px;
  content:'';
}
.bell:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  border: 2px solid #6d6d6d;
  height: 3px;
  width: 3px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
  left: 5px;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
}
.bell:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #6d6d6d;
  bottom: -6px;
  height: 4px;
  width: 8px;
  border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px;
  left: 5px;
  animation: swinging .6s linear infinite alternate;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
}
@keyframes swinging{
  0%{transform: rotate(10deg) translateX(-2px)}
  100%{transform: rotate(-10deg) translateX(2px)}
}
```

```html
<div class="bell">
  <div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Also refer the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cronqqoe/). Run the fiddle to reproduce the bug.

Comment: Its visible in your fiddle.I've checked in both chrome and FF.

Comment: @vivek i have edited my blog with an image attached how it will appear when the animation starts

Comment: but it works fine in the fiddle and code snippet.

Comment: tap on run button and carefully notice the bell, u can reproduce

Answer (score 2):

I just gave `z-index: 999` to the `.bell div` and it solved the issue.

It's looks like a bug with the chrome. firefox and IE, it's working fine.

The div is initially at the right position. all I did is to bring the div in front using z-index.

```css
.bell{
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    width: 18px;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
    background: #6d6d6d;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    animation: swinging .3s linear alternate;
    animation-delay:2s
}
.bell div{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 3px;
    width: 120%;
    background: #6d6d6d;
    left: -2px;
    content:'';
    z-index: 999; // increase the z-index
}
.bell:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    border: 2px solid #6d6d6d;
    height: 3px;
    width: 3px;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
    left: 5px;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
}
.bell:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: #6d6d6d;
    bottom: -6px;
    height: 4px;
    width: 8px;
    border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px;
    left: 5px;
    animation: swinging .6s linear infinite alternate;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
}
@keyframes swinging{
    0%{transform: rotate(10deg) translateX(-2px)}
    100%{transform: rotate(-10deg) translateX(2px)}
}
```

```html
<div class="bell">
  <div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know the exact reason, the div is at correct position initially, I just need to bring it forward using z-index. Might be a chrome bug